# Where, Case, and In SAS SQL

Tags: sql, sas

Trying to use an '`in`' within a 'case' within a 'where' clause in SAS SQL

I am trying to write an `SQL query in SAS` that utilizes a "`where`" clause. Within this "`Where`" clause, I need to use a "`case`" statement, and within this, an "`in`" statement. Is this possible?

Something like this:

```
proc sql;
connect to $$$$$;
create table test1 as 
select * from $$$$$ (
    select 
      line1, 
      line2 
    from 
      $$$$$ 
    where 
      line1 not in case when line2 = 1 then ('0', '1', '2') else ('3') end
  );
quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need to use a `case` statement within the `where` clause, because you can write a logically equivalent condition without a `case` statement:

```sql
where (line2 = 1 and line1 not in ('0', '1', '2'))
      or (line2 <> 1 and line1 not in ('3'))
```

Comment: Thank you! Just checking anyway, can is there a way of using a case with 'not in'? The code i gave above returns an error

Comment: You could use a `case` statement with [`not`] `in` like that, but then you would have to write a complete subquery that includes the `case`, after the `in`.

Answer (score 2):

To continue using `case`, rearrange the mind a little and change the code to

```
where
  case
    when line2 = 1 then line1 not in ('0', '1', '2')
    else                line1 not in ('3')
  end;
```